# Not getting the same interpretation as expected results

Tags: sql, oracle

I am supposed to make a SELECT statement that is similar or exactly the same as the expected outcome. What am I doing wrong?

I am supposed to interpret a Query Processing Plan, and write out the SELECT statement that would give me said plan. The plan looks like this:

[image: Expected outcome]

The statement that I tried was:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT * FROM LINEITEM RIGHT JOIN ORDERS ON L_ORDERKEY = ORDERS.O_ORDERKEY
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON ORDERS.O_CUSTKEY = CUSTOMER.C_CUSTKEY
WHERE L_TAX NOT IN (SELECT L_TAX FROM LINEITEM WHERE L_TAX>20);
```

My results are:
    [image: My outcome]

This is my first time using anti join, so I'm not sure if I'm right. I do not know if HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI SNA is similar to HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI. Also, why does it say "L_TAX" = "L_TAX"? Isn't that redundant? And why does it do a Hash Join outer, and then another hash join?

Comment: Out of curiosity, someone asked you to reverse engineer a query just based on its explain plan? You know that explain plans can change based on what the query optimizer decides, and that decision even involves existing indexes, the amount of data, the value of input parameters, and possibly other volatile information.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yeap, I have to basically do that. From the explain plan, I have to come up with the statement that would make said plan. I understand that there can be different ways that it will be interpreted. The thing is, I got very confused, and not sure if what I have, is similar to what is required.

Comment: The logical way to write this query would be, I think, to start with customer, (inner?) join orders, and left join line items. Then have the various checks in the join. Long story short, I would assume that the original authors of the query are not idiots, so start with writing a sensible query, and then go from there by trial and error to see how close you can get. But unless this is for some training, I think it's a weird assignment, tbh. :-)

Comment: Btw `WHERE L_TAX NOT IN (SELECT L_TAX FROM LINEITEM WHERE L_TAX>20);` This feels to me like a very complicated way to write `WHERE L_TAX <= 20`. Also, this whole check should go to the join condition, since `LINEITEM` is optional (right join), and by having the check in the where clause, you effectively make it an inner join. And personal preference: don't use right join. :p

Comment: @GolezTrol I agree with you on the L_TAX. The reason I did that was so that I could get it to show up as the filter. I will try and give it a shot and see what I can get from this! Thank you for your suggestions!